# Dynamic binding model for use in HttpClient

Tags: model-binding, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Web Api that takes a `complex` object and adds it to the database.

```
var myWidgit= new Widgit() { 
  Name = "WidgitName", 
  Price = 50, 
  Category = "Appliance" };

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/createwidgit", myWidgit);
```

I need to make a one off call to the API and I would like to avoid creating a separate class file for `Widgit`.

Is there a way to define the `Widgit` class and assign it values in the method that makes use of it? Sort of like a `dynamic` class just used in this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out ...

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/createwidgit", new StringContent(string.Format("Name={0}&Price={1}&Category={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("WidgitName"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(50), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Appliance"), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```

Essentially the `dynamic` object I was looking to create is accomplished using

```
new StringContent(string.Format("Name={0}&Price={1}&Category={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("WidgitName"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(50)), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Appliance"), Encoding.UTF8, 
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Sorry I could not figure out better formatting